# Grok pattern for extracting complicated line structure?

Tags: regex, logstash-grok, grok

I have single line like

`sgcib.solstis.core.dao.referential.InsertionMonitoringDao:10:37:36.860 [SOLSTAIRJVM1: customService :false-persistor-3-] INFO  Begin updating insertion_monitoring table: analysisProcessId=1000000648897, insertionMonitorId=9153700, binFileName=TIS_MRM_Meteor_DeltaSpot_RA_SMCPLX_47769.2x2.2016-11-29-00-00-00_1480377600000.bin.tisdevweb043.SOLSTAIRJVM1`

Here, extract value [SOLSTAIRJVM1: customService :false-persistor-3-] as **thread field** AND **1000000648897 as one analysisProcessId field** and **9153700 as another insertionMonitorId field**.And  fields values are optional in the input line,incase not found in input line fields must be shown with empty value.

Can any one please suggest how to write pattern?

Comment: Maybe `\[(?<thread>[^\]\[]*)].*?analysisProcessId=(?<analysisProcessId>\d+).*?insertionMonitorId=(?<insertionMonitorId>\d+)`?

Comment: Thanks let me test in the url https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ .nope no luck

Comment: Please can suggetst using above url.I am trying out

Comment: The regex above was tested at the link before posting. SO adds garbage chars into comments. See https://regex101.com/r/UNk06w/2, copy the pattern from the regex101 fiddle.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have got the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\[(?<thread>[^\]\[]*)].*?analysisProcessId=(?<analysisProcessId>\d+).*?insertionMonitorId=(?<insertionMonitorId>\d+)
```

**Description**:

- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `(?<thread>[^\]\[]*)` -
- `].*?` - a literal `]` followed with any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible up to the first
- `analysisProcessId=` - a `analysisProcessId=` substring
- `(?<analysisProcessId>\d+)` - Group "analysisProcessId" capturing 1+ digits
- `.*?insertionMonitorId=` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible up to and incl. the first `insertionMonitorId=`
- `(?\d+) - Group "insertionMonitorId" capturing 1+ digits

See the demo screen:

[image]

Comment: Could you suggest along with extracting the fields.How to take original exact line as another field ?

Comment: Do you mean the whole string should be a field by itself? Something like [`^(?<whole>.*?\[(?<thread>[^\]\[]*)].*?analysisProcessId=(?<analysisProcessId>\d+).*?insertionMonitorId=(?<insertionMonitorId>\d+).*)`](https://regex101.com/r/UNk06w/3).

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: For example for given input "anystring [anystring1] IN" if the pattern is .*?(?<thread_name>\[.*\]) here thread_name field value is anystring1 .I want if [anystring1] does not exist then value of thread_name to "".what is going to be the new pattern ?

Comment: Hey hi you are back thanks  [anystring1] is not extracted as field value using (?<thread_name>(?:\[.*\])?).Sorry i have used (?<thread_name>\[.*\]) not .*?(?<thread_name>[.*])

Comment: Is the `[anystring1]` always at the end of the string? If yes, `(?<thread_name>(?:\[.*\])?)$` should work.

Comment: Thanks.[anystring1] may not be at the end of string always.

Comment: Ok, then use `(?:(?!\[[^\]\[]*\]).)*(?<thread_name>(?:\[[^\]\[]*\])?)`

Comment: Ohh thank you very much.It works.Looks you added many changes.It is getting difficult to analyse for me. Similarly how can make all fields value to empty if pattern not exist in the input line for the below .*?(?<thread_name>\[.*\]).*?(analysisProcessId=)*(?<analysisprocessId>\d*).*?insertionMonitorId=(?<insertionmonitorId>\d*).*?binFileName=*(?<binfilename>.*.bin*)  Please help me i do analyse later to have much understanding

Comment: By the way i have used input line   "sgcib.solstis.core.dao.referential.InsertionMonitoringDao:10:37:36.860 [SOLSTAIRJVM1: customService :false-persistor-3-] INFO  Begin updating insertion_monitoring table: analysisProcessId=1000000648897, insertionMonitorId=9153700, binFileName=TIS_MRM_Meteor_DeltaSpot_RA_SMCPLX_47769.2x2.2016-11-29-00-00-00_1480377600000.bin.tisdevweb043.SOLSTAIRJVM1"

Comment: You will be able to do that all by yourself after learning the [tempered greedy token](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970). Replace all `.*?` with the corresponding TGT.

Comment: Thanks for the motivation

Comment: Hey sorry for reping i could see [anystring1] as field value but need anystring1 as value how to avoid [ and ] in value ?

Comment: Put the `[` and `]` outside the capturing group. `\[(?<group>[^\]\[]*)\]`. If it is optional, wrap with `(\[(?<group>[^\]\[]*)\])?`

Comment: Hi can you please help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426198/extracting-many-optional-comma-separated-fields-using-grok-pattern   Not getting how to take pattern that ends with ,