# Extracting many optional comma separated fields using Grok Pattern?

Tags: regex, logstash-grok, grok

I have below example in single line of text:

```
valuationType=RiskAnalysis,
commandType=SpreadRA,
pricing_date=20161230 01:00:00.000, 
priority=51,
CamelFileLastModified=1483346829000,
CamelFileParent=/home/tisuat52/mount/tis/shared, message_size=239450,
solstis_set_name=OFFICIAL, 
CamelFileRelativePath=TIS_RISKONE_SpreadRA_CREDITASIACNH_OFF_CreditGamma_Ido_RA_2016-12-30_1483138799000_Input.bin, 
command_status=OK, 
commandName=CREDITASIACNH_OFF_CreditGamma_Ido_RA, 
calculator_timestamp=20170102 04:35:41.257, 
CamelFileAbsolute=true, 
CamelFileLength=53248.
```

Want to extract all text (mixed string, that is `.*`) right side of `=` to field whose name is left side of `=` and each field is separated by `,`.  And important is order is fixed but some fields are optional. If the Field is not present grok should create a field with empty value.

Comment: Have you considered [kv filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) with `default_keys`?

Comment: no did not used kv filters yet.But fields names are fix to what is there on left side of =.

Comment: I think `kv filters` will do here. Just define the default_keys for each field you need to appear in the result.

Comment: Ok thank you.How it would be for commandType=SpreadRA, ?